# SOAP with Attachment Client in .NET

Tags: wcf, soap, soap-client

I'm attempting to build a C# SOAP client which uses **SOAP with Attachment**. From what I've read, my understanding is that `WCF` does not have an out-of-the-box solution for this.

Does this mean that the proxy generated from the server's **WSDL** via `svcutil.exe` won't be of use to me?

Comment: Yes, it means that. SwA is obsolete.

Comment: Are there .NET utility classes which assist in composing these soap/xml messages?

Comment: There's no utility to automate this process, but you can define the SOAP using either DataContracts or MessageContracts. You also have System.Runtime.Serialization.IExtensibleDataObject for serializing and deserializing the data.

Comment: @Brian: DataContracts and MessageContracts can be useful even when building an SWA SOAP client?

Comment: They can be helpful building WCF soap client.

Comment: So not for me since I'm using SWA.

Comment: @Brian: Can I trouble you to take a look at the sample soap request in [this](https://www.emedny.org/selfhelp/SOAP/eMedNY_Meds_History_Service_User_Guide_1.1.pdf) user guide and let me know whether I'm even dealing with SwA? A tech support guy mentioned SwA to me, but when I look at the request, I don't see why he said that.

Comment: Sorry for the slow response ... I'm in Europe. If it were me, I'd try to get a sample message from the people that own the host - the kind of info you get with Fiddler. Then you can use that as the template for your message. I've never used SWA, either, so I don't think I'd be of much help there.